# Calculations Dependent On Multiple Drop-down Selections

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following spreadsheet calculating my household outgoings with a number of categories to choose from multiple drop-down lists (Cols **B, C**).

[image: Spreadsheet]

In **Column H**, with the header **Outgoings**, I would like to sum the columns **D** and **E** in two rows based on the selections made in the drop-down lists in **J2, J3** which act as filters for said calculation. These drop-down lists reflect the **Bill Type** in **Column B**, and the **Category** in **Column C**.

As an example, if I selected from the drop-downs in **Column J**: **Personal**, **Credit/Debit** then I would like the two rows in **Column H (Outgoings)** to be populated with the total sum of the rows **D** and **E**, respectively, for where the **Bill Type** and **Category** in **B** and **C** match **Personal** and **Credit/Debit**.

Along with the above conditions, if there is no selection in either of the **Column J** drop-downs, I would like the rows in **Column H (Outgoings)** to simply provide the calculation of the incomes in **D, E** (Row 2) minus the remaining sum of each column (total outgoings, i.e. `D2:D`).

I'm a little new with the syntax required to perform more complex calculations and was wondering if this was achievable in spreadsheets, specifically, in Google Sheets.

Comment: Pls share a spreadsheet. People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in cell H2:

```
=if(J2&J3="",
sum(filter(D:D,C:C="Income"))-sum(filter(D:D,C:C<>"Income")),
sum(filter(D:D,B:B=J2))+sum(filter(D:D,C:C=J3))
)
```

[image]

This in H3:

```
=if(J2&J3="",
sum(filter(E:E,C:C="Income"))-sum(filter(E:E,C:C<>"Income")),
sum(filter(E:E,B:B=J2))+sum(filter(E:E,C:C=J3))
)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked with one amendment; using `sum(filter(D:D,B:B=J2, C:C=J3))` instead of `sum(filter(E:E,B:B=J2))+sum(filter(E:E,C:C=J3))` to operate as an AND instead of an OR operation between both rows B and C.